# After upgrading to JDK 11 my SOAP response is different

Tags: soap, java-11, spring-ws

I have a SOAP service implemented with Spring-WS and after upgrading to Java 11 (from 1.8) the generated response is slightly different:

[image: Difference in response]

Being the first one with Java 11 and the second one with Java 1.8.

This difference triggers the following error in the service:

```
2024-03-15 09:30:34.750 ERROR 10252 --- [nio-8150-exec-1] a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[messageDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find SOAP wrapper for element [xenc:EncryptedData: null]] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find SOAP wrapper for element [xenc:EncryptedData: null]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.find(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:590) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.find(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:578) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.getFirstChildElement(ElementImpl.java:660) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.BodyImpl.getPayloadQName(BodyImpl.java:439) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.BodyImpl.hasFault(BodyImpl.java:151) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapBody.hasFault(SaajSoapBody.java:55) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.hasFault(AbstractSoapMessage.java:62) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getFaultCode(AbstractSoapMessage.java:68) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:94) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:288) ~[spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
```

I have no idea about why Java 11 is missing the `ns2` part and how to fix it.